# Loading shapefiles into ArcSDE geodatabase using web application?

Tags: shapefile, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-flex-viewer

We are developing a web GIS using Flexviewer and we want to allow users to upload a shp file and insert it into a ArcSDE geodatabase.  I think there are two steps at least.

1. upload the shp file (zip) to a directory on the server
2. call some function to load it to the ArcSDE geodatabase

How can I do this using ArcObjects or Geoprocessing service (ArcPy)?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems pretty straightforward. Grab files from ftp or network drive, unzip and import them into your geodatabase. I would likely wrap the steps in a batch file, where I would run the move and unzip through command line and then call the python script to work the GIS magic.

[Stack Overflow - Moving file locations through command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743094/how-can-i-move-all-the-files-from-one-folder-to-another-using-the-command-line)

[Stack Overflow - Unzipping files through command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021557/how-to-unzip-a-file-using-the-command-line)

You'll want to use the arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion method to convert the shapefile (see [Feature to Geodatabase - ArcGIS help page](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#//001200000021000000)):

```
# Name: FeatureClassToGeodatabase_Example2.py
# Description: Use FeatureClassToGeodatabase to copy feature classes
#  to geodatabase format
# Author: ESRI

# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set environment settings
env.workspace = "C:/data"

# Set local variables
inFeatures = ["climate.shp", "majorrds.shp"]
outLocation = "C:/output/output.gdb"

# Execute TableToGeodatabase
arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(inFeatures, outLocation)
```

In addition, you'll probably want to make sure that you are running some form of scan or virus protection on anything coming from outside sources.